# Cocos2D scale animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm trying to do something pretty simple in Cocos2D and running into trouble. I would like to scale a CCNode with animation.

In the code below you will see what is happening

```
// load object of CCNode subclass GameOver
_gameOver = (GameOver*)[CCBReader load:@"gamePlayItems/GameOver"];
[self addChild:_gameOver];
_gameOver.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
_gameOver.position = ccp(.5, .75);
```

At this point the CCNode is on the screen at the proper position

```
    //scale it up
    _gameOver.scale = .2;
    id scale = [CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:.8 scale:1];
    CCActionEaseBackOut* bounce = [CCActionEaseBackOut actionWithAction:scale];

    [_gameOver runAction:bounce];
```

The animation is never fired. The GameOver object is on the stage scaled to .2

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here. I even quickly recreated your setup and it runs just as expected. I'm guessing you've overlooked something?

Comment: You seem to be scaling the animation correctly.
So you must be missing the condition to fire the animation, try looking over your code again.  eg on -(void)update:(CCTime)delta if (something == thisThing) then fire code

Comment: Turns out the issue was [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause] was being called right before the animation was called. Thank you for your time.